Show that algebra over finite set $M$ is a $\sigma$-algebra

Let be $M$ a non empty finite set and $\mathcal{A}$ an algebra over $M$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_sets) then $\mathcal{A}$ is already a $\sigma$-algebra.

Actually, we only have to show that it is closed under countable unions. I was wondering if it is possible to prove this statement simply by an inductive argument like this:
base case: $M$ contains one element which we denote by $m_1$, then $\mathcal{A}_1=\{\emptyset,\{m_1\}\}$ is clearly a $\sigma$-algebra.
induction hypothesis: if $M=\{m_1,\dotsc,m_n\}$ then $\mathcal{A}_n$ is closed under countable unions.
induction step $n\to n+1$: Let's consider an arbitrary countable union $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^\infty A_i$, where $A_i\in \mathcal{A}_{n+1}$ and $A_i\subseteq M=\{m_1,\dotsc,m_{n+1}\}$. If $m_{n+1}\in \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ then we know that $A_i\setminus\{m_{n+1}\}\in\mathcal{A}_{n+1}$ for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$ because an algebra over $M$ is closed under set difference. But also $A_i\in \mathcal{A}_n$ because it is a finite union of elements of $\{m_1,\dotsc,m_n\}$. So we can apply the induction hypothesis to $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^\infty A_i\setminus\{m_{n+1}\}$ and know that $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^\infty A_i\setminus\{m_{n+1}\}\in\mathcal{A}_n$. This allows us to express $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^\infty A_i\setminus\{m_{n+1}\}$ by a union of finite elements of $\{m_1,\dotsc,m_n\}$. Hence, $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^\infty A_i=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^\infty A_i\setminus\{m_{n+1}\}\cup\{m_{n+1}\}$ is a finite union of elements of $\{m_1,\dotsc,m_{n+1}\}$ and therefor $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^\infty A_i\in\mathcal{A}_{n+1}$ which completes the induction step. Finally, the statement is true for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

I am not sure if it is legit to switch between the two $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal{A}_n$ and $\mathcal{A}_{n+1}$? Does it work?

@abomasnow, I understand your point and indeed it seems obvious. However, I wanted to prove it rigorously just for the sake of practising and getting familiar with it.
